# What should I do to make my code work in R markdown?

Tags: r

I am using 'flights' dataset from 'nycflight13' package.
In the 'flights' dataset the missing value of the 'dep_time' variable means a cancelled flight. I need to calculate the proportion of cancelled flights over the scheduled flights for each subsample defined by the 'carrier' variable and then sort these proportions from the highest to the lowest. Here is my code:

```
flights %>% group_by(carrier) %>% 
   summarize(p = across(dep_time, ~sum(is.na(.))) / 
                +                   across(sched_dep_time, ~sum(!is.na(.)))) %>% arrange(desc(p))
```

The problem is that my code works in R file but doesn't work in R markdown. Could anybody tell me how to adjust my code in R markdown? Thank you so much

Comment: Did you load the required libraries in your RMarkdown file? (`library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)`)

Comment: Yes, I did, and it still shows no result

Comment: You should show us a minimal R Markdown file that contains your code and fails if you want help figuring out why it doesn't work.